# Starting on NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, attributes, nhibernate-mapping

I'm starting to use NHibernate and I'm kind of lost. I'm just trying to do the smallest code possible to map a simple table and query all of its members.

I know I should have started with xml mapping but, instead, I'm trying to use attribute mapping (feels cleaner and more productive than fluent and easier to maintain than xml)

My class - which maps a table named "cars" goes like this:

```
[Class(NameType = typeof(Cars),
       Lazy = true,
       Table = "Cars")]
public class Cars
{
    [Property(Column = "Prefix")]
    public virtual int Prefix { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "Status")]
    public virtual int Status { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "Ip")]
    public virtual string Ip { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "Port")]
    public virtual int Port { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "CommStatus")]
    public virtual int? CommStatus { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "TimeToRetry")]
    public virtual DateTime? TimeToRetry { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "dsc")]
    public virtual string dsc { get; set; }
    [Property(Column = "Company")]
    public virtual int Company { get; set; }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml config file goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">
  NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
  NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=.;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=somethingelse!@#$;</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And, finally, I'm starting the session factory and a session in the smallest way possible

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ListAllData()
    {
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Configuration dbConfig;
        dbConfig = new Configuration();
        dbConfig = dbConfig.Configure();
        dbConfig.AddAssembly(typeof(Cars).Assembly);
        sessionFactory = dbConfig.BuildSessionFactory();

        using (ISession currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var carList4 = currentSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Cars)).List<Cars>();
            var carList = currentSession.CreateCriteria<Cars>().List<Cars>();
            var carList2 = currentSession.QueryOver<Cars>().List<Cars>();
            var carList3 = currentSession.Query<Cars>().ToList<Cars>();
            Assert.IsNotNull(carList);
            Assert.IsTrue(carList.Count > 0);
        }
    }
```

However all carList variables are empty lists - I don't know what I could be doing wrong... - No exceptions are thrown and... I'm really at a loss of what went wrong (and yes - there is data in the database)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly got what I was doing wrong. Apparently NHibernate will *always* require a xml "file" mo matter how.

That's why, in the initialization code, I had to use

```
        dbConfig.AddInputStream(
            HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(
                typeof(Cars).Assembly));
```

Instead of

```
        dbConfig.AddAssembly(typeof(Carros).Assembly);
```

Finnaly, I've just learnt that every class in NHibernate requires a primary key - that's why I also had to change the Cars class so that

```
    [Property(Name = "fHash")]
    public virtual string fHash { get; set; }
```

Became

```
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "fHash")]
    public virtual string fHash { get; set; }
```